# Как правильно трансформировать запрос из SQL в LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Есть два класса:

```
class A {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

class B {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public A A { get; set; }
}
```

Эти же 2 класса отражены в таблицах (Oracle, но не суть - не было под рукой другой СУБД)

```
table A {
  number Id <PK_A>
  varchar2(1) Name
}
table B {
  number Id <PK_B>,
  number AId <FK_A>
}
```

Есть такой запрос (`CTE` приведена для примера):

```
with a as (
  select 1 as id, 'X' as name from dual union
  select 2 as id, 'Y' as name from dual),
b as (
  select 1 as id, 1 as AId from dual union
  select 2 as id, 1 as AId from dual union
  select 3 as id, 1 as AId from dual)
-- Результирующий запрос
select a.Id, a.Name, count(1) as cnt_B
  from a
  left join b on a.Id = b.AId
  group by a.Id, a.Name
  order by a.Id
```

Результат:

| ID | NAME | CNT_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 3 |
| 2 | Y | 1 |

Как в результате LinQ запроса получить такой же результат, что и в результирующем запросе?

Мои нерабочие попытки(в `LINQPad`):

```
var query = from a in A
            join b in B on A equals B.A
            group b by a into result
            select new
            {
              A = result.A,
              BCount = result.Count();
            };

query.Dump();
```

--

```
var query = from a in A
            from b in B
            where b.A == a
            select new
            {
              A = result.A,
              BCount = result.Count();
            };

query.Dump();
```

--

```
var query = from a in A
            join b in B.DefaultIfEmpty() on a equals b.A into result
            select new
            {
                Field1 = result.a,
                BCount = result.Count()
            };

query.Dump();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где неправ и куда копать.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался:

```
var query = from a in A
            join b in B.DefaultIfEmpty() on a equals b.A into result
            select new
            {
                A = a,
                BCount = result.Count()
            };
            
query.Dump();
```

Люблю stack:

1. Неделю думаешь
2. Решаешь запостить вопрос сюда
3. Перечисляешь возможно удачные попытки
4. Самостоятельно находишь решение
5. ???
6. PROFIT!!11